# Let $a(n)$ be a convergent sequence with limit $L$, and let $K$ e $N$. Show that $a(n+k)$ is also convergent with limit $L$

Tags: limits

I was thinking of using the definition of a limit but am not sure with how to start.

Comment: Hint: if $n\ge N\Rightarrow |a_n-L|<\epsilon$, then.....or better, note that $a_{n+k}$ is a subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: What does "K e N" mean?

Comment: K is an element of the natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of limit:

> $b_{n} \to L$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M \in \mathbb N$, such that if $m > M$, then $|b_m - L| < \epsilon$.

We want to show that $a_{n+k} \to L$, right? So we need to start with some $\epsilon > 0$.

At  this point,  we know that $\lim a_{n} = L$. From definition, using the $\epsilon$ we started with, there is some $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_{n} - L | < \epsilon$ whenever $n > M$. Now, if $n > M$, then $n + k > M+k$, right?

So, if $(n+k) > M+k$, then $|a_{n+k} - L| < \epsilon$ is true. So, our new $M$ is just $M+k$. So, for any $\epsilon$, we have found an $M$ satisfying the limit conditions. Hence, it follows that $a_{n+k} \to L$.